# Problem using Array[] in Do-While Loop

Tags: java

Here is a method called placeShips() that I am calling via another method (which is called by a ButtonListener).  But when all are called, I get a NullPointerException on the deepest nested line - System.out.println(ships[i]);.  The array has been declared and initialized above this code in the constructor.  It is set to be equal to a constant integer which equals 3.  I've put a simple string in that printout and it works.  But whenever the array gets involved, it becomes messy.  What is going wrong?

NUM_SHIPS, NC_EMPTY, NC_SHIP, and all the labels/buttons have been made as well.

```
private Ships ships[];

*-----Constructor begins here-----*
Ships[] ships = new Ships[NUM_SHIPS];
*-----Constructor ends here-----*

ships[0] = new Ships("Aircraft Carrier", 5, false);
ships[1] = new Ships("Battleship", 4, false);
ships[2] = new Ships("Cruiser", 3, false);

public void placeShips()
{
    statusLabel.setText("Press [Play]");
    int shipsPlaced = 0;

    do
    {
        int randomRow = (int)(Math.random()*ROWS);
        int randomCol = (int)(Math.random()*COLS);

        if (gameBoard[randomRow][randomCol] == NC_EMPTY)
        {
            gameBoard[randomRow][randomCol] = NC_SHIP;
            shipsPlaced = shipsPlaced + 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SHIPS; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(ships[i]);
            }
        }
    }while (shipsPlaced < NUM_SHIPS);
}
```

Comment: Is NUM_SHIPS equal to ships.length ?

Comment: is placeShips() and ships[] array, members of the same class ? Have you tried putting a breakpoint at println statement and see if ships array has ship objects or is the array empty ?

Comment: Do you have a class level array variable called "ships"? Are you sure you're assigning to it before you try to use it in PlaceShips()? Also, its better to construct your for loop as `for (int i = 0; i < ships.Length; i++){...}`

Comment: NUM_SHIPS is equal to ships.length.

Comment: About the class, I have a separate Ships.java file that holds the class and constructor for Ships.

Comment: About the assignment.  I'm pretty confident that it is assigning them, the first lines in the constructor are the ships[0], ships[1]... lines.  And the method is only being called on button press, after the GUI loads.

Comment: How about Ships.toString()? Try implementing an empty toString().

Comment: It builds and compiles fine.  But when I press the Deploy Ships button, which effectively calls the placeShips() method, is when I get the nullPointerError in the output.

Comment: to Hai Minh Nguyen,  I tried putting that insteadl of the ships[i] but it resulted the same.  I put a simple println above the if, and it was output before the error.  Same goes when I put it below the shipsPlaced increment.  This might help:  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

You have a class level array variable : `private Ships ships[];`, yet you define in your constructor `Ships[] ships = new Ships[NUM_SHIPS];`. Are you ever assigning to the class level variable? you could try

```
/* Class Level */
private Ships _ships[];

/* In constructor */
_ships = new Ships[NUM_SHIPS];

/* In PlaceShips() */
for (int i = 0; i < _ships.Length; i++)
{
    if(_ships[i] != null)
    {
        System.out.println(_ships[i].toString());
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work then debug the code to find which object is actually throwing the exception

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your constructor is only initializing a local variable named ships.  You say you have:

```
-----Constructor begins here-----*
Ships[] ships = new Ships[NUM_SHIPS];
*-----Constructor ends here-----*`
```

But it seems like you really want

`ships = new Ships[NUM_SHIPS];`

Comment: This also helped, turns out I didn't need the Ships[] in the beginning.  It no longer spits out the error! Thanks everyone.